# Should I use Nullable<'a> or Option<'a> in F#?

Tags: f#

Which way is more idiomatic to use Nullable<'a> or to use Option<'a> for representing a nullable int?

Answer (score 5):

Option is far more idiomatic in F# code.

It has far nicer syntax when used in `match` and has large amounts of support from the standard library.

However, if you plan to access the code from C# or some other language you should probably expose the interface with `Nullable` which is easier to use in C#.

Answer (score 5):

As John said, `Option<T>` is definitely more idiomatic type in F#. I would certainly use options as my default choice - the `Option` module provides many useful functions, pattern matching works nicely on options and F# libraries are generally designed to work with options.

That said, there are two cases when you might want to use nullable:

- When creating arrays of optional values - `Nullable<T>` is a value type (sort of) and if you create an array `Nullable<T>[]` then it is allocated as continuous memory block. On the other hand options are reference types and `option<T>[]` will be an array of references to heap-allocated objects.
- When you need to write some calculations and propagate missing values - in F# 3.0, there is a module `Microsoft.FSharp.Linq.NullableOperators` which implements various operators for dealing with nullable values (see [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh370984.aspx)) which lets you write e.g.:

  ```
  let one = Nullable(1)
  let two = Nullable(2)

  // Add constant to nullable, then compare value of two nullables
  (one ?+ 2) ?>=? two
  ```

Comment: Actually, you can trivially define the equivalent Microsoft.FSharp.Linq.OptionOperators that will do the same for Options, so that's one less reason

Comment: You do need to use Nullables when you're using a LINQ query over IQueryable, as it will translate nullables properly but not options. I think that's probably the reason Freebase uses nullables instead of options